# How to expand Vuetify/HTML table to needed width without cutting off content?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

Given a Vue app based on Vuetify using the [table](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/tables/) component. When using this setup

( [Reproduction link](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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) )

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-container fluid>
        <v-table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Col 1</th>
              <th>Txt</th>
              <th>Checkbox Column</th>
              <th>Select ( plain txt )</th>
              <th>Chips</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>
                <v-text-field label="Label goes here" model-value="some text goes here"></v-text-field>
              </td>
              <td>
                <v-checkbox label="Label for checkbox goes here" :model-value="true"></v-checkbox>
              </td>
              <td>
                <v-select label="Select with plain text" :items="[1, 2, 3]" :model-value="1"></v-select>
              </td>
              <td>
                <v-select label="Select with chips" multiple chips :items="['aaaaaaa', 'bbbbbbbbb', 'Some more items here']" :model-value="['Some more items here']"></v-select>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </v-table>
      </v-container>  
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

The table looks fine on large screens

[image]

but the table breaks on smaller screens

[image]

This table should work for desktops ( no need for responsive mobile support ) and has a dynamic amount of columns ( at least more than 20 ). I want each column ( and its elements ) to expand to a "human readable" width. So no label, chip, text etc. should be cut off. It's perfectly fine if the horizontal scrollbar is huge. But I would like to avoid using a hardcoded columns width because each column should only take the space it needs to display its content.

I hope it's not a Vuetify problem because the table relies on basic HTML but I don't know how to fix it via CSS.

Comment: set `min-width` on table-row

Comment: @Anilkumar I don't know how much I would need. The table is dynamic. And `style="min-width: 3000px"` didn't work

Comment: set `width="fit-content"` or `width="max-content"`

Comment: does it work for you? It didn't work for me

Comment: The table is perfectly fine. The issue is with the v-select elements.
While you can fix the chips by adding 
`overflow: unset;
    white-space: break-spaces;
    height: max-content !important;
    max-width: unset;`
to v-chip class, the label is much tricker as it is in `absolute` position. I would try using another component

Answer (score 2):

As you are using Vuetify 3 [`<v-table>`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/tables/) component and it is just a simple wrapper component around the HTML `<table>` element. I did not see any inbuilt `props` to setting the width for the table as well as for the columns. Hence, you can only achieve this at this point of time by applying the custom width on `td` and `th` with the help of CSS.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const { createApp } = Vue
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify

const vuetify = createVuetify()

const app = createApp({
  template: '#app-template'
}).use(vuetify).mount('#app')
```

```css
th, td { min-width: 200px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@vuetify/nightly@3.1.6/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@vuetify/nightly@3.1.6/dist/vuetify.css"/>

<script type="text/x-template" id="app-template">   
<v-table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Col 1</th>
              <th>Txt</th>
              <th>Checkbox Column</th>
              <th>Select ( plain txt )</th>
              <th>Chips</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>
                <v-text-field label="Label goes here" model-value="some text goes here"></v-text-field>
              </td>
              <td>
                <v-checkbox label="Label for checkbox goes here" :model-value="true"></v-checkbox>
              </td>
              <td>
                <v-select label="Select with plain text" :items="[1, 2, 3]" :model-value="1"></v-select>
              </td>
              <td>
                <v-select label="Select with chips" multiple chips :items="['aaaaaaa', 'bbbbbbbbb', 'Some more items here']" :model-value="['Some more items here']"></v-select>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </v-table>
</script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: so there is no way to tell the elements not to shrink?

Comment: @baitendbidz I tried a lot actually and spend a good amount of time but did not get success. So I came up with this solution and I think there is no harm in using this solution and worked for your code sample.

Comment: I tried to improve your answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75603731/19698303 but it's still not a "nice" solution :/

Comment: @baitendbidz I can understand that but out of the box this is the only solution I came up with.

Answer (score 0):

set `white-space: nowrap;` property for `td` if the dynamic content is not lengthy plain text or if you do not have an issue with presenting it on single line.

Example code base is added for reference.

```css
td {
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
    td {
      padding: 15px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    td {
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
    td {
      padding: 15px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Col 1</th>
        <th>Txt</th>
        <th>Checkbox Column</th>
        <th>Select ( plain txt )</th>
        <th>Chips</th>
        <th>Col 1</th>
        <th>Txt</th>
        <th>Checkbox Column</th>
        <th>Select ( plain txt )</th>
        <th>Chips</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
          test data test
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle1" name="vehicle1" value="Bike">
<label for="vehicle1"> I have a bike sdahsv dhasvd asvdagsdga v</label><br>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>

<select name="cars" id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes sd svahsv asvdgasVD Gasvdghsadvhgas vdagsvdhgasdhgasdvgh</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
        </td>
        <td>
          sample data sample data
        </td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
          sample data sample data sample data sample data sample data sample data sample data sample data sample data sample data sample data
        </td>
        <td>
          sample data sample data sample data sample data
        </td>
        <td>
          sample data
        </td>
        <td>
          data
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: that didn't work for my code example :/

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to [Rohìt Jíndals answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75553532/10871073), I found a temporary workaround to prevent elements from cutting off content.

It is not a perfect solution, as gigantic labels and chips still won't fit.

```
<style scoped>
/* elements with content requiring more than 200px will still struggle... */
.v-text-field,
.v-select {
  min-width: 200px;
}

/* do not cut off chip content */
.v-select v-chip {
  overflow: visible;
}

/* expand chip */
.v-select .v-field__input {
  width: unset;
}
</style>
```

But now no content is cut off. [Demo](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)